# Keep border at parent's height while centering child vertically

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to have a vertical divider between my colums that alway stays the same height, no matter how many linebreaks its column has. I use `border-left` for this, it's handy because it's gone when there's no column on the right.

At the same time I want each column content to be vertically centered. I used to center it by adding auto margin, but that removes a bit of the border.

Does someone have a good idea how to get these two requirements (center content vertically + same vertical divider height) together without needing to add CSS -
just using Bootstrap 4 classes?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  #1 Border correct, but content not vertically centered:
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col">
  1 of 2
  <br>
  hihi
  <br>
  hihi
</div>
<div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
  2 of 2
</div>
<div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
  2 of 2
  <br>
  hihi
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  #2 Border too short, but content vertically centered:
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
<div class="col">
  1 of 2
  <br>
  hihi
  <br>
  hihi
</div>
<div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
  2 of 2
</div>
<div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
  2 of 2
  <br>
  hihi
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- it's best to expand the snippet to full page if you can't see 3 columns -

Answer (score 0):

when you use display flex, the blocks move to the inline-block position. That's why border sizes are changing. I used the `border-right` property on the **first column** to get the image you wanted, and I used the `align-self-center` property on the  second column you wanted to center. That's how your problem seems to be solved.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <p>
        #1 Border correct, but content not vertically centered:
      </p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col border-right border-dark">
        1 of 2
        <br>
        hihi
        <br>
        hihi
      </div>
      <div class="col align-self-center d-none d-md-block">
        2 of 2
      </div>
      <div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
        2 of 2
        <br>
        hihi
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        #2 Border too short, but content vertically centered:
      </p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100 ">
      <div class="col border-right border-dark">
        1 of 2
        <br>
        hihi
        <br>
        hihi
      </div>
      <div class="col align-self-center border-dark d-none d-md-block ">
        2 of 2
      </div>
      <div class="col border-left border-dark d-none d-md-block">
        2 of 2
        <br>
        hihi
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that you can still see the border when only the the first column is visible at a certain width - which I don't want - that's why I put the border to the left on the 2nd instead of to the right on the first. And in your example the 3rd column is not vertically centered.